# C# insert custom value selected item from checkedlistbox to dataviewgrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im working in a lab for covid. We are sending result via excel. I made a template for easy edit excel file. I searched too much but i cant find solution for this request.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9UWV.png]

in this picture after selected items and push "tamamlandı" button, i want to change dataviewgrid second column change custom data

for example: if selected 1,5,13,48 in checkedlistbox, change 1,5,13,48 rows second column data to "POZ"

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag. | Do you using data binding? Show us the code.

Comment: i dont wrote any code this is just a visual view but i add "ID" column. So just i need;

Select number from checkedlistbox, after push "tamamlandı" button, change COVID-19 column data to POZ

Comment: Please edit to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all checked items via `CheckedItems` property. Then you can use the `foreach` statement to traverse it.

```
private void btntamamlandı_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        // get the checked item value
        // rowindex starts from 0, so need to subtract 1
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString()) - 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = "POZ";
    }
}
```

---

**Update: delete selected rows**

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // store checkedListBox1 selected index
    List<int> indexs = new List<int>();

    foreach (var i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        indexs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString()) - 1);
    }

    // selected row count
    int count = indexs.Count;

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(indexs[0] - index);
        indexs.RemoveAt(0); // remove the first item
    }
}
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you for helping <3

Comment: i need just one command @Kyle Wang.  Can you share delete selected rows?

Comment: @BerkayKaplan You can call [Rows.RemoveAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.removeat?view=netcore-3.1). But when an item is deleted, the index of the selected row will change. You can declare a list to store them. I have updated the answer, hope it can help you.

Comment: Want tanks a lot man you are amazing. You are fix my all problems